# How to query multiple tables with one input in Talend?

Tags: sql, database, db2, etl, talend

For a simplified example, I have a DB2Input -> tMap -> DB2Output. In the DB2Input I wrote a query that takes data from two tables.

I get the warning: Parameter(query): Schema is different from the query.

Do I just need to specify one of the tables? Thanks.

UPDATE:

Well I think I got it. You click the 'edit schema' button and manually put in the columns your query selects.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I tend to do in those situations (only querying two tables) :

```
DB2Input --------
                -
               tMap ------- DB2Output
                -
DB2Input --------
```

In other words :

- One DB2Input per tables queried
- Join is made within the tMap using the second table as a "lookup" table (ex: http://bekwam.blogspot.com/2012/05/efficient-lookups-with-talend-open.html)

However, when you already have a complex made query, you can use one Input component like you're mentioning in your EDIT.

In this case, you can press the "Guess query" button and Talend may succeed in detecting the result schema. For that, you will need to have the "built-in" schema option selected.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will better for us to first create a view by writing complex query in database and then use that view in talend component as table to avoid creating multiple input and join's in talend  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a non-repository query (manually entered/adjusted/whatever) and you get the "Schema is different than the query" warning, you can use the "guess schema" button.  If the system is performing correctly, it should look at the fields you have in your query and give you an output schema to match them.  You may have to adjust the field types if the system doesn't understand them.

I use this (writing my own input SELECT queries) a lot to control input from one db based on records in another db...